# Лог ошибок, отлов причины краша

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте. Крашится приложение. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно организовать логирование. В LogCat мелькает куча мусора. Со stack trace не смог разобраться. Спасибо.

```
07-23 01:32:29.586 15022-15022/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=34; index=34 at pollux.download_gif.MainActivity$2.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:54)
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java)
at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java)
at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Строку с ошибкой нашел, буду искать решение)

**UPD**
Ошибка найдена: первый из двух массивов имел на одно значение больше, ввиду чего одному элементу не было "пары" из второго массива, что приводило к крашу.

Comment: а может покажете стектрейс?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для логирования используйте класс Log. У него имеются несколько режимов для разных ситуаций: например Log.v(означает подробный, если дословно).

Маленький курс по stack trace:

[Первый скрин http://i7.5cm.ru/i/cNSe.png](http://i7.5cm.ru/i/cNSe.png)

1)Переходим на вкладку Android Monitor.

2)В поле, под цифрой "2" на первом скрине - вписываем слово "exception", тем самым выделяя блок с ошибками и убирая ненужные логи и мусор.

3)Ищите синие ссылки на строку с кодом, на которой приложение упало.

4)Это главная строка, показывающая основную информацию об ошибке, обычно, именно в ней хранится описание ситуации, из-за которой возникло исключение. В примере, что Вам привел - я намеренно убрал инициализацию вьюхи во фрагменте, тем самым вызвав NullPointerException - компилятор вам об этом и пишет в этом сообщении.

[image: Второй скрин]

Для того, что бы логировать, вам необходимо сделать следующее:

1)Под цифрой 1 показан синтаксис и принцип логирования. То есть это статический метод класса `Log.уровень_логирования();`.
Сначала вписываете тег, затем значение, которое будет выводиться по этому тегу.

2)В поле, под цифрой 2 нужно ввести ваш тег, их может быть несколько для каждого отдельного лога - они не связаны.

3)Все в той же вкладке Android Monitor будет выводиться то, что вы писали по тегу.

Вроде, это все что нужно знать для логирования. Оно работает по тем же принципам, что и `System.out.print("");` в джаве(можете вывести значение строки\числа\поля класса и т.п).

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ! Про `log.уровень` знал, а вот фильтр `exception` новое. Благодаря фильтру нашел строку с ошибкой. Обновил первый пост.

Comment: @Pollux `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=34; index=34 at pollux.download_gif.MainActivity$2.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:54)` у вас на строке 54 массив выходит за границы. Сделайте massive.length - 1;